# Intel WIDI Technology on Windows 8 Desktop App

Tags: c#, windows

How to use Intel WIDI technology on Windows 8 Desktop Application using C#?

Comment: were you able to implement WiDi in your desktop application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [Intel WiDi Extensions SDK](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?lang=eng&DwnldID=20410). It contains the .NET Library and C# samples to use WiDi.

You can find some additionnal information on [Building Intel WiDi Applications for Ultrabook](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/10/02/building-intel-widi-applications-for-ultrabook).

Comment: it is Possible to integrate Intel WIDI in windows 8 Metro App.

Comment: I don't know about Windows 8 Metro App. Intel is not so active to promote WiDi to the developers, they don't even mention Windows 8 in the WiDi SDK...

Comment: No it is not possible to Integrate WiDi for Metro Apps